# Elements not being read

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, jquery-ui-dialog

I've created a dynamic list of pages using json and have output those to a . Elements being created by the for loop seem to be unable to be read by JS or CSS. For example all of the  links that are part of the for loop should be being turned into buttons through jquery-ui but are not. Dialog box appears to be working in JS Fiddle. Now I have attempted to use .live with still no luck. Now an attempt with on and still the same results. This seems like a DOM issue any help would be greatly appreciated :).

jsfiddle link

http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=3QRhR6vf5i

The href is setup as such

```
<a id="delete" class="ui-button-text" href="function/variable">Delete</a>
```

default.js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(function () {
    $.getJSON('webpages/json_data', function (o) {

        for (var i = 0; i < o.length; i++) {
            $('#contentList').append('<div class="contentBox ui-widget-content"><div class="cHeader">' + o[i].page_headline + '</div><div class="cOption"><a href="create/' + o[i].id + '" class="ui-button-text">Edit</a></div><div class="cOption"><a class="ui-button-text" rel="' + o[i].id + '" id="delete" href="json_del">Delete</a></div></div>');
        }
    });

    $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        resizable: false,
        height: 180
    });

    $("#delete").on("click", "a", function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var targetUrl = $(this).attr("href");
        var id = $(this).attr("rel");
        var delItem = $(this).parent().parent();
        $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
            buttons: {
                "Confirm": function () {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "GET",
                        url: href,
                        data: "id=" + id,
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function () {
                            delItem.remove();
                        }
                    });
                },
                Cancel: function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });

        $("#dialog-confirm").dialog("open");
    });
});
});
```

dialog-confirm

```
<div id="dialog-confirm" title="Delete site page?">
 <p><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float:left; margin:0 7px 20px 0;">  </span>
 This item will be permanently deleted and cannot be recovered. Are you sure?</p>
 </div>`
```

webpages controller

```
function json_del()
{
    $id = $this->uri->segment(3);
    $delete = $this->_delete($id);
}

function _delete($id)
{
    $this->load->model('mdl_webpages');
    $this->mdl_webpages->_delete($id);
}
```

webpages model

```
function _delete($id)
{
    $table = $this->get_table();
    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    $this->db->delete($table);
}
```

Comment: It would help if you would put the relevant code into a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/). P.S. You can sidestep the issue of the default action by using "data-href" instead of "href" for your attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some sleep and a bit of research I needed to set classes and then call to them.

default.js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(function () {

    $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        resizable: false,
        height: 300
    });

    $(".delete").click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var targetUrl = $(this).attr("href");
        var id = $(this).attr("rel");
        var delItem = $(this).parent().parent();
        $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
            buttons: {
                "Confirm": function () {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "GET",
                        url: targetUrl,
                        data: "id=" + id,
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function () {
                            delItem.remove();
                        }
                    });
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                },
                Cancel: function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });

        $("#dialog-confirm").dialog("open");
    });

    // setter
    var disabled = $( ".disabled" ).button( "option", "disabled" );
    var delicons = $( ".delete" ).button( "option", "icons" );
    var editicons = $( ".edit" ).button( "option", "icons" );
    var deltext = $( ".delete" ).button( "option", "text" );
    var editext = $( ".edit" ).button( "option", "text" );

    // getter
    $( ".disabled" ).button( "option", "disabled", true );
    $( ".delete" ).button( "option", "icons", { primary: "ui-icon-trash", secondary: null } );
    $( ".edit" ).button( "option", "icons", { primary: "ui-icon-pencil", secondary: null } );
    $( ".delete" ).button( "option", "text", false );
    $( ".edit" ).button( "option", "text", false );
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you problem is the js script called before the DOM is ready.
please Wrap you JS code into

```
$(document).ready(function(){

// your code

})
```

Comment: I have added that and it does not seem to fix the issue. It seems to work in jsfiddle though.